# ReactJs - Iterating over an object to create form fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I've decided to iterate over an array and create `Form.Field` (semantic-ui). Here is my static code that works like a charm:

```
export default class OrderChange extends Component<Props> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    state = {}
    handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value })
     render() {
                  <Form.Field>
                    <Radio
                      label='A'
                      name='radioGroup'
                      value='this'
                      checked={this.state.value === 'this'}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </Form.Field>
                  <Form.Field>
                    <Radio
                      label='B'
                      name='radioGroup'
                      value='this1'
                      checked={this.state.value === 'this1'}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </Form.Field>

    });
```

I was working on it to creating dynamic data. Firstly, I created an object like this:

```
    const radios = [
        {
            name:'j',
            value:1
        },
        {
            name:'k',
            value:2
        }
    ];
```

Then, I was trying to iterate on it:

```
                {radios.map(function (radio, index) {
                    return (
                        <Form.Field>
                            <Radio
                                label={radio.name}
                                name='radioGroup'
                                value='this'
                                checked={this.state.value === radio.value}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Field>
                    );
                })}
```

However, I've got this error:

```
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

in this line:

```
 checked={this.state.value === radio.value}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In your case ,`state` declared as a `class properties` and not an `instance property`.

```
 state = {} //class property will not available on this object
```

Either do `state` declaraion in constructor

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {};   // now state available on this object
}
```

and `checked={this.state.value === radio.value}` will work

or remove `this` from here.

```
checked={state.value === radio.value} // with class property state,it will work.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to declare state in constructor to access the state using `this` object

```
 constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {value:somevalue}
    }
```